# rviz not working well

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide to install the Rviz.
I have used the following command :
sudo apt-get install rviz.
I have followed the tutorial from http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes and the package has been created and built.
But opening the Rviz is not showing me the output,It is simply showing me a blank screen with grid-lines,not the expected robot.
After following external sources ie: "Mastering ROS For robotic programming" , then also the launch files are responding well, but the output is not coming on Rviz software.

I tried reinstalling but it didn't help.

Also, i get the following warning while performing the rosrun command:

```
ayushas@ayushas-hp-550:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun using_markers basic_shapes
```

Output:

```
[ WARN] [1478182897.733692243]: Please create a subscriber to the marker
```

Seems like there is an issue with the installation.
Kindly help me in this regard.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247174/rviz-not-working-well/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-03**:
Have you loaded the Markers display as instructed by the tutorial? I've bumped your karma so you should be able to post a screenshot of rviz.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2016-11-03**:
As per the tutorial, i have crated the file "basic_shapes.cpp" and have changed the "CMakeLists.txt".
But i am not able to correlate my rviz screen with the following tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide.
rviz is not showing such features.Have attached the screenshot.Thank you for the help

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-03**:
The rviz style has changed a little in the past 5 years, but the buttons still have the same labels and are still in the roughly same location. I can still see the `Add` button in your screenshot.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2016-11-03**:
But the output should have been a sphere or cube or else. Kindly let me know why am i getting a blank screen instead of the output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to click the `Add` button and add `MarkerDisplay` to display your markers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2016-11-03**:
Thank you so much sir. I am very new to these topics and i spent few hours for such a small mistake. With such helping comments like yours, it becomes very easy for newbies like us to learn.
Thank you sir.
Regards